# Does "for of" loop in javascript stop until receiving value from "await" on every iteration?

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous

In this article https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/7746/looping-with-async-await
I read that we wait on every iteration of "for of" loop, but after I checked it in codesandox I realized that all the promises start being executed simultaniously, so the loop doesnt stop on every iteration, but the code inside every iteration stops. **Does this article have incorrect info**?

---

Screenshot from article - [image]

---

My code

```js
const promises = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  promises.push(
    new Promise((res, _) => {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        res(i);
      }, 2000);
    })
  );
}

(async () => {
  for (let promise of promises) {
    const r = await promise;
    console.log(r);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Your example does not the same what the example in the linked tutorial does. The tutorial creates a new `Promise` on every iteration of the loop. You're creating a bunch of `Promise`s and are then awaiting them one at a time - which means that all `Promise`s are already resolved when the first iteration of the loop has finished.

Comment: What Andreas said is correct -- your first loop basically says "create a promise that resolves in 2 seconds", and then it does that 4 times, immediately, with one promise being created immediately after the other. Assuming it takes 1 millisecond to create such a Promise, and 2 seconds to resolve each promise, the first promise will be resolved at 2001ms, the second at 2002ms, the third at 2003ms, etc. (very over-simplified logic but it's basically like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new Promise, the internal function of that promise runs as soon as it gets the opportunity to.

Instead, you could do something like this to make the internal function wait until it's called from your second loop:

```js
const promiseFuncs = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  promiseFuncs.push(
    () => new Promise((res, _) => {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        res(i);
      }, 2000);
    })
  );
}

(async () => {
  for (let promiseF of promiseFuncs) {
    const r = await promiseF();
    console.log(r);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Just like the example in the tutorial...